# java.lang.StackOverflowError when using Kryo to serialize objects with references to each other

Tags: java, apache-spark, kryo, kryonet

I have a graph-like object that I'm sending from server to client that contains `nodes` that have `adjacencyLists`.

I have something similar to this:

```
Clearing c1 = new Clearing(1, 134, 151);
Clearing c6 = new Clearing(6, 250, 88);

c1.adjacentByPath.add(new Path(1, c6));
c6.adjacentByPath.add(new Path(1, c1));
```

Each time I send the object that contains these clearings, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Server" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:448)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:79)
    ......
```

Is there a workaround for this in Kryonet? Thanks

Comment: In case anyone in the future is wondering, I just used the JavaSerializer instead of Kryo for the objects with this problem and it worked fine

Comment: its late answer but I had encountered and fixed the problem (by seeing kryo docs) in the below way. If you are okay you can consider accepting the answer. so that it will be pointer to other users who had the same issue... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*It was late answer, but recently I encountered this and was able to replicate as well as fix.*

---

This happens whenever large object graph is used in kryo serialization...

> **Fix** :
>    1) Try to fix this by tail recursion examples [here](https://linkedin.com/pulse/scala-recursion-demo-normal-java-style-well-tail-ram-ghadiyaram/)
>    2) Increase stack size by specifying `Xss` in vm options

`-Xss1m`( or increase as per your requirements) as suggested by [Esoteric software documentation which developed Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/README.md#very-large-object-graphs)

#### Very large object graphs :

> Stack size
>
> The serializers Kryo provides use the call stack when serializing
>   nested objects. Kryo does minimize stack calls, but for extremely deep
>   object graphs, a stack overflow can occur. This is a common issue for
>   most serialization libraries, including the built-in Java
>   serialization. The stack size can be increased using -Xss, but note
>   that this is for all threads. Large stack sizes in a JVM with many
>   threads may use a large amount of memory.

***Imp Note for apache spark + Kryo users:***

> In case of spark I set SparkConf object
>   `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=...` (along with -Xmx -XX options)
>   programmatically or you can also mention that in `spark-default.conf`